# Display a number near the review link

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be nice to have a number between parenthesis near the review link to know how many review tasks are available.

Something like this : `review (2)`

At the moment we have to go to the review page to see if there is something to do.

Comment: That *was* its normal behavior. Its not displaying a notification for me at all using Chrome right now.

Comment: I'm using Firefox and I never saw something. Maybe because I'm a new 500+ reputation user !

Answer (score 1):

It actually does display it. [You need 10k rep to see it, though.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726)

[image]

Comment: With 500 rep I can see the review link but I need to have 10K rep to see the notification number. That's no sense...
Thank you for the answer.

Comment: My guess is that since the number shows everything in the queue and isn't personalized, they don't want to show the number if there's a possibility you can't act on the items in the queue.

Comment: Ok, but why 10K and not 3K ? It seems to be the rep necessary to see all the review tasks.

Comment: It is 2k reputation.